# How do I automate key strokes using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, automation, keypress

I'm trying to automate a lengthy workflow of clicks in an internal application for work. I'm actually a recruiter, and I want to bind a series of browser actions to one key (using ShortKeys Chrome extension).

I've worked out everything in JavaScript except one field that I can't seem to change the value of. I don't have access to the source code, but the HTML element is as follows:

```
<input type="text" class="inputtext textInput" name="time_display_time" value="12:54 pm" placeholder="Add a time" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead_list_u_m_2" aria-haspopup="true" role="combobox" spellcheck="false" aria-label="Add a time" id="u_m_3" tabindex="0">
```

I'm attempting to change the "value" attribute to a specific time, but using

```
element.value = "new_time";
```

doesn't seem to work. I think the problem is that this particular input dynamically generates a drop down of suggested values based on what the user is typing. Therefore, if I want to change the value of the input, I need to simulate a user typing in "9:30 am", for example, and then hitting the return key. Anyone have any advice?! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The open-source program [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) might be what you are searching for. It is really easy to configure.

Answer (score 0):

for jquery ,
try

```
 $('#u_m_3').val('new time');
```

or

```
 $('#u_m_3').attr('value','new time');
```

for javascript:

```
document.getElementById('u_m_3').setAttribute('value','new time');
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question! So those methods change the value of the field visually. However, when I submit the form, the default value, that is there when the window loads, is the one that is submitted -- not the new one. This is why I need to simulate keystrokes, so the page will dynamically generate a drop down, and I can select one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! In this particular instance, there was a hidden input that was measuring the time in the future to set the follow up in seconds. Element below. So I just needed to change the value of THAT input to the number of seconds in the future I wanted to set the follow up.

```
<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" class="hiddenInput" name="time" value="40680">
```